# How to stop from while loop in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried to design a pyqt gui in when I press "x"  will stop `run` function `a` counter , what should i do ?

I only know to use the following code

```
    def closeEvent(self,event):   
          pass
```

Logic Code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import time
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 
        self.thread = MyThread(self)        
        self.thread.trigger.connect(self.textBrowser)
        self.thread.start()       
           
    def textBrowser(self,a):  
       self.ui.textBrowser_4.clear()           
       self.ui.textBrowser_4.append(str(a))        
     
    def closeEvent(self,event):   
          pass  
 
    
    class MyThread(QThread):
        trigger = pyqtSignal(str) 

       def run(self):
            a = 0
            while True:     
                a = a + 1
                self.trigger.emit(str(a))
                time.sleep(1)
                

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    MainWindow = MainWindow()    
    MainWindow.show()      
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

GUI Code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(944, 587)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 310, 181, 41))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 141, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textBrowser_4 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 300, 241, 61))
        self.textBrowser_4.setObjectName("textBrowser_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "counter"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an initiator and an is_running variable in your Thread class like so :

```
def __init__(self):
    self.is_running = True
```

Then make your loop depend on the truthness of this new variable :

```
def run(self):
    a = 0
    while self.is_running:  
         ... your logic here
```

And finally when you want to exit in closeEvent() :

```
self.thread.is_running = False
```

Cheers

Comment: I have this problem AttributeError: MyThread' object has no attribute is_running , class MyThread did not get `is_running`  variable

Comment: @user19212551 you need to put `self.is_running` into the `__init__` function of `MyThread`, then do `self.thread.is_running = False` inside `closeEvent`

Comment: Exact, I've updated the code @user19212551

Comment: Note: it's common to set the default flag as a class attribute, and explicitly set it *again* at the beginning of `run()` (so that the thread can be restarted again if required, when it's finished). It's also good practice to call [`wait()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait) on the thread (after attempting to stop it) in order to quit it gracefully. Also consider using [`requestInterruption()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption) and [`isInterruptionRequested()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested).